# Currency validation with Decimal using regex

Tags: java, regex

Currency validation with Decimal using regex

Hi All,
I am trying to use a regex for one of my scenario.
So i get currency in a string format i have to check the below scenario

- length can be between 1-6
- the currency may or may not contain decimal.
- decimal is allowed only once.

123.45 - valid
 1234.. - Invalid
 12.3 - Valid
 123456 - valid
 123456.7 - Invalid

I tried the regex ^[0-9.]{1,6}$

but it does not validate the third scenario (decimal is allowed only once).
Please help me with your inputs.

Comment: You should use `DecimalFormat.parse()` for this, not a regex. It knows a lot more about the rules than you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
^(?=[\d.]{1,6}$)\d+\.?\d+$
```

Here, this `(?=[\d.]{1,6}$)` positive look ahead ensures that the total length of text is one to six characters and `\d+\.?\d+` ensures the number is in correct format and `^` and `$` are start and end anchors to ensure full string match and not partial.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VtYIMA/1)**

Java code,

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("123.45","1234..","12.3","123456","123456.7");

list.forEach(x -> {
    System.out.println(x + " --> " + (x.matches("^(?=[\\d.]{1,6}$)\\d+\\.?\\d+$")?"Valid":"Invalid"));
});
```

Output,

```
123.45 --> Valid
1234.. --> Invalid
12.3 --> Valid
123456 --> Valid
123456.7 --> Invalid
```